# How to move data from azure data lake to cosmosdb on a schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-lake

I have data that needs to be moved from azure data lake to cosmosdb. The data is small, maybe < 1000 records per day. Each record is maybe < 5kb. I need this data to be exported from azure data lake and imported to cosmosdb as a timed job. The data should be moved 1 time per day. Ideally this would be configurable to many times a day. Right now I am considering using a function app to spin up on a schedule and make this export/import. However this feels wrong. I feel like there must be a better way to do this. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: I have been looking at azure data factory but this also seems overkill as this is an ETL tool. I just need the E and the L no T. Extract and load to cosmos.

Comment: Data factory is what you're looking for . It's also easy to configure since it's code less. Just because it is an ETL doesn't mean it is wrong if you don't do any transform.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without data factory? What would be super sweet is if an event trigger mechanism could be configured so that an event was emitted every time a new record(s) was added to the table i am interested in. Then I could go get that specific record. Is that possible?

Comment: you can try this template, [Delta copy from a database with a control table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table)  or  you can go to "copy data tool" to get a pipeline, which use trigger scheduled time as a variable to read the new rows only from source database. checkout [snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9CyB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use copy data tool, with schedule task for `source`: Azure Data Lake and `sink`: CosmosDB

See: [Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool#start-the-copy-data-tool)

[image]

[image]